# WSO2 APIM carbon console is not accessible through aws elastic load balancer

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, aws-elb

Hi I have running wso2 docker image running inside aws instance. I am accessing wso2 apim services(store/publisher/carbon console) through aws ELB. And I have mapped ELB with DNS name inside Route 53.

Problem is I am able to access store and publisher(https://wso2.vitkutin.com./store/ and https://wso2.vitkutin.com./publisher/) successfully but when I'm trying carbon console https://wso2.vitkutin.com./carbon/ gives me below error.I am able to successfully curl -v -k https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp inside docker container. Can someone help me to solve this error ?

```
    <am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
    <am:code>404</am:code>
    <am:type>Status report</am:type>
    <am:message>Not Found</am:message>
    <am:description>The requested resource is not available.</am:description>
    </am:fault>

Route 53 DNS name is configured inside carbon.xml and apimanager.xml as shown below :
carbon.xml
<HostName>wso2.xxx.com.</HostName>
<MgtHostName>wso2.xxx.com.</MgtHostName>

apimanager.xml   
<GatewayEndpoint>http://wso2.xxx.com.:80,https://wso2.xxx.com.:443</GatewayEndpoint>

<APIStore>
   <URL>https://wso2.xxx.com.:443/store</URL>
</APIStore>

<APIPublisher>
   <URL>https://wso2.xxx.com.:443/publisher</URL>
</APIPublisher>
```

Comment: Do you see entries for `/carbon` in http access logs? in `repository/logs/`

Comment: Yes log from http access log file : 18.236.211.130 10.0.1.230 - - [29/Jul/2018:18:11:09 +0000] "GET /carbon HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)"
- 10.0.1.230  - [29/Jul/2018:18:11:09 +0000] "- - " 404 - "-" "-"  

And log from wso2carbon.log is :
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-07-29 18:11:09,560]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /carbon {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}

Comment: on chrome browser shows below error message :
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://wso2.xxx.com./carbon' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://wso2.org/favicon.ico'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

As per the access log, it seems the request is sent to 8280 or 8243, instead of 9443. Please check your loadbalancer rules.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. Basically I have used aws ELB with listeners on port 80 and 443 and rule is forward traffic to ec2 instance where docker image is running. Also I am just doing health check under port 8243 and path is /services/Version. The strange thing is with same load balance I am able to access store and publisher which runs on 9443 port only. For store and publisher url I have modified apimanager.xml file.

Comment: Do I need to modify any configuration file for path /carbon/ as well ? I read quite many wso2 documentation but couldn't find any configuration file which I should change for path /carbon/.

Comment: Below are changes done in apimanager.xml   
<GatewayEndpoint>http://wso2.xxx.com.:80,https://wso2.xxx.com.:443
</GatewayEndpoint>

<APIStore>
   <URL>https://wso2.xxx.com.:443/store</URL>
</APIStore>

<APIPublisher>
   <URL>https://wso2.xxx.com.:443/publisher</URL>
</APIPublisher>

Comment: Those are not related to the issue. You must be having some kind of loadbalancing rule which forwards 443 to 9443 only for /store and /publisher apps. I can't say how though.